# Looking a PHP library for creating and validating forms

Tags: php, forms, class, validation

I work with my own homemade framework and I want a library (classes) PHP 5 for generating form with validation and if possible with support ajax support HTML5.

I already did a search and found PFBC (PHP Form Builder Class) and HTML_QuickForm but it is obsolete.

Do you know of others?

Comment: I'm involved in the development of the pfbc project.  Out of curiosity, why did you pass on this option?  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: As I'm not using any framework, I'm using this class as standalone with some extensions. According to me as noob, coding looks pretty good,  allows writing some extensions and shows [many inline examples](http://www.imavex.com/pfbc2.x-php5/examples/elements.php), which are well documented. Big work done for these guys.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the poster decided not to use PFBC, particularly -- would be nice to have an update.  

... This post led me to PFBC while looking for just this kind or resource.  I'm excited.  I especially like the precise and limited scope of PFBC -- just forms, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have toyed with the [Symfony Form Component](https://github.com/symfony/Form) and [Symfony Validator Component](https://github.com/symfony/Validator). They are pretty nice to work with. The only downside is documentation. They are mostly documented in the context of the entire Symfony framework and not as separate components.

Also, [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html) is pretty good as well (although I personally dislike they Decorator approach for HTML generation). It integrates with the Zend_Filter and Zend_Validate components.

It's even possible to mix these two. For a project of mine I have used Zend_Form together with the Symfony Validator. This takes some integration work, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I have tried to use Zend components but now it no longer standalone.
Same thing for symfony version 2 since it
If ever you know of other similar librairiee but standarlone, come say on this topic;)

Comment: They *are* standalone, really. I'm using them as stand-alone components in one of my applications right now. For Zend, I don't know if you can download and install it as separate components, but you can certainly just use what you want and not bother with the rest. As for Symfony, they explicitly provide separate git repositories containing separately usable compnents. See the links I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I like this for jQuery forms, and the CSS style is a great start for most pages too...

http://sprawsm.com/uni-form/

You should use PHP (server side) validation in addition to this library, though...